# Can't figure out the complete path of JSON environment for Kitchen/Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I don't know how to set the full path of environement JSON file.

I guess the path is composed of multiple level, but it's not described in [doc](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html)

The path is now `environment/dev.json`, what is a correct path/name ? My tests on hash in cookbooks fails

Sample JSON :

```
{ "foo": { "bar": "base" } }
```

I need to test from my cookbooks :

```
if node[:foo][:bar] == "base"
    puts "ok"
end
```

For this snippet, can anyone explain this syntax to query a hash ? Is it Ruby or Chef specific syntax ? Why not `node['foo']['bar']` ?

My .kitchen.yml file :

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  environments_path: 'environment'
  client_rb:
    environment: dev

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-1204

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[mysql::default]
    attributes:
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the Ruby/Chef syntax, that's Ruby syntax.

Ruby hashes (aka hashtables or dictionaries in other languages) can have any object as a key, but in the Ruby world it's most common to use [symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html).

JSON objects can only have strings as their keys, so when you convert JSON into a Ruby hash it really depends on the developer as to whether they choose to leave the keys as strings or convert them to symbols to be more idiomatic.

You can see there's a flag in `JSON.parse` called [symbolize_names](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) which will automatically convert them for you.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an environment file, it needs to look the [it says in the docs](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#environment-formats), but the default path is `test/integration/environments/`.

Comment: And how to name the JSON file please?

Comment: In your case, dev.json